# Дискорд бот и упоминание

Tags: discord, discord.py

Хочу сделать так, чтобы при упоминании бота, он что-то на это отвечал. Однако как это сделать, я не понял.

```
async def <Тут стоит ID>( ctx ): 
    await ctx.send("Что-то хотели?")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого не нужно создавать функцию с формой упоминания бота - это не будет работать.

Проще всего создать обработчик сообщений - `on_message()` и проверять, есть ли упоминание бота в списке всех упоминаний, которые содержит сообщение.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    else:
        if bot.user in message.mentions:
            await message.channel.send('Что-то хотели?')

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

**Не забудьте указать токен от вашего бота!**